# Android WebView getHitTestResult() in async task crashes the app

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-webview

I have implemented context menu on WebView with **Save image** as an option. When user clicks on that option image is downloaded in an **asynctask** DownloadImage().
Inside **doInBackground** of DownloadImage asynctask I have code like this:
`HitTestResult result = webview.getHitTestResult();
 if (result.getType() == HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
       // code to download and save the image
    }`

This was running fine on all android versions upto 4.4. Now I changed the **targetSdkversion** from 17 to 19 and my app start crashing on android 4.4 when clicking on **Save image** option. Checking crash logs I get runtime exception on the line `HitTestResult result = webview.getHitTestResult();` . But it still continues to run fine on Android 4.4 if I set targetSdkVersion to 17 again.  
 I think it is somehow related to new Android 4.4 (API level 19) that is based on Chromium. More specifically related to this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#Threads
Now I am wondering wether I should set targetSdkversion to 17 and release the build or do some other workaround to fix this issue ?
And what is the best solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the docs say: the solution to this is to only call WebView methods on the UI thread. The exception is intentional - new applications should not call WebView methods from background threads. The preferred solution is to set targetSdk to 19 and update your code.

In your case it looks like you could just get the value of webview.getHitTestResult().getType() from the 'Save image' menu option handler (which runs on the UI thread, right?) and save that as a field on your AsyncTask.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am calling async method from menu option handler So I could get the value there only.  For this I have to refactor the code and pass necessary values as parameters in async task. If I go by the approach mentioned in doc I could wrap my current code like this:    `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { // current code for image download and save }});` Is this approach okay ?

Comment: @r.bhardwaj - if the code doesn't block and doesn't do IO then it's probably fine, but I'm guessing there was some reason it was written as an async task in the first place.